# Spark - How to create a Spark dataframe that contains array of values in one of its columns for countVectorizer model

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, countvectorizer

I am trying to execute Spark's countVectorizer model. As part of this requirement, I am reading a csv file and creating a Dataframe (inp_DF) out of it.

It has 3 columns as shown below

```
+--------------+--------+-------+
|         State|Zip Code|Country|
+--------------+--------+-------+
|      kentucky|   40205|     us|
|       indiana|   47305|     us|
|greater london|    sw15|     gb|
|    california|   92707|     us|
|      victoria|    3000|     au|
|         paris|   75001|     fr|
|      illinois|   60608|     us|
|     minnesota|   55405|     us|
|    california|   92688|     us|
+--------------+--------+-------+
```

I need to create a 4th column within the same dataframe that contains the array of values of all these 3 columns such as

```
|      kentucky|   40205|     us|   "kentucky","40205","us"
|       indiana|   47305|     us|   "indiana","47305","us"
|greater london|    sw15|     gb|   "greater london","sw15","gb"
|    california|   92707|     us|   "california","92707","us"
|      victoria|    3000|     au|   "victoria","3000","au"
|         paris|   75001|     fr|   "paris","75001","fr"
|      illinois|   60608|     us|   "illinois","60608","us"
|     minnesota|   55405|     us|   "minnesota","55405","us"
|    california|   92688|     us|   "california","92688","us"
```

**Question 1 : Is there any easy command like .concat to achieve this ?**

This array is needed because the input for countVectorizer model should be a column containing array of values. It should not be a string datatype as mentioned in the below error message :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   requirement failed: **Column State must be of type equal to one of the
>   following types: [ArrayType(StringType,true),
>   ArrayType(StringType,false)] but was actually of type StringType**.   at
>   scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnTypes(SchemaUtils.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.validateAndTransformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.transformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.fit(CountVectorizer.scala:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.examples.ml.CountVectorizerExample$.main(CountVectorizerExample.scala:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.examples.ml.CountVectorizerExample.main(CountVectorizerExample.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=300m;
>   support was removed in 8.0

I tried to create an array from those 3 columns of input dataframe but the array elements are enclosed within square brackets [ ].

Sample code snippet is given below for your reference

```
// Read Input Dataset for countVectorizer Logic
val inp_data = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "True").option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").option("nullValue", "")
      .load("Input.csv")

// Creating a Spark Dataframe from the Input Data
val inp_DF = inp_data.toDF()

// Creating an array from Spark Dataframe Columns
val inp_array = inp_DF.select("State","Zip Code","Country").collect()
      println(inp_array.mkString(","))

// fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer()
      .setInputCol("State")
      .setOutputCol("features")
      .setVocabSize(4)
      .setMinDF(2)
      .fit(inp_DF)
```

**Question 2 : How to remove square brackets [] from those array elements and create a new column in a dataframe with the values of the array ?**

**Question 3 : Can we supply single column value as input to the countVectorizer model and get features as output ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `array` function to create the `array column` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val inp_array = inp_DF.withColumn("arrayColumn", array("State", "Zip Code", "Country"))
```

which should give you output as

```
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
|State        |Zip Code|Country|arrayColumn              |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
|kentucky     |40205   |us     |[kentucky, 40205, us]    |
|indiana      |47305   |us     |[indiana, 47305, us]     |
|greaterlondon|sw15    |gb     |[greaterlondon, sw15, gb]|
|california   |92707   |us     |[california, 92707, us]  |
|victoria     |3000    |au     |[victoria, 3000, au]     |
|paris        |75001   |fr     |[paris, 75001, fr]       |
|illinois     |60608   |us     |[illinois, 60608, us]    |
|minnesota    |55405   |us     |[minnesota, 55405, us]   |
|california   |92688   |us     |[california, 92688, us]  |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
```

and you can use this `dataframe` in your `CountVectorizerModel` as

```
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("arrayColumn")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .setVocabSize(4)
  .setMinDF(2)
  .fit(inp_array)
```

that answers your first two questions.

Now answering your third question. **YES** you can use only one column in `CountVectorizerModel` but for that you would need to convert the column to `ArrayType(StringType,true)` which can be done by using the `array` function as above.

Suppose you want to use `State` column in `CountVectorizerModel`. then you can change the datatype of `State` column to `array` by doing

```
val single_arrayDF = inp_DF.withColumn("State", array("State"))
```

and use it as

```
 val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("State")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .setVocabSize(4)
  .setMinDF(2)
  .fit(single_arrayDF)
```

I hope the answer is helpful.